# SQL statement to identify a record having at least 6 months of data

Tags: postgresql

My table records data for few drilling 'Wells' with identification as 'Well_ID', and data is captured every second (captured in 'received_time' column). Now, I want to write a query that will return me only those wells that has captured at least 6 months of data on the basis of 'received_time'.

I have tried 'between' but this will return wells that has some data between the date range I have provided, doesn't necessarily give me wells that have drilled for that entire period.

```sql
select distinct(well_id) 
from table1 
where received_time between '2023-06-01' and '2023-12-31'
```

To clarify, different wells are drilled for different period of time. Some might be drilled for 2 months, while some for 10 months. Data is collected for every second. What I'm looking for is to identify the wells that have drilled at least for 6 months, which in turn will give me 6 months of data for every well. The date range which I have mentioned in the query was just an example, it doesn't necessarily have to be within that month range or year.

Attached is sample of how the data looks like -

[image]

Can someone please help?

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: Please clarify what "at least 6 months of data" means. Data exists for each caleandar month? Data exists sometime between six months ago and today?

Comment: *"don't think that gives me what I want."* Why don't you *think* it gives you what you want? We can't run your query, nor do we know what results you expect, so we don't know why what you have isn't doing what you think it is(n't).

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: @jarlh - the data is recorded every second. Also attached a sample of data. I hope that clarifies. This is a sample of data for one specific well with a unique well_id.

Comment: Do you mean you require data for each second during a 6 month period, or just once in a while (how often)? Calendar month or arbitrary 6 month period?

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING` to return each well_id where the latest received_time is at least 6 months after first the received_time.

```
select well_id 
from table1
group by well_id
having max(received_time) >= min(received_time) + interval '6' month
```

Comment: You could also check that `count(received_time) > 6`. Assuming that you have one `received_time`/record a month, that will be sufficient to check that there wasn't a four month gap between uses. Is that a fair assumption?

Comment: @SmellyCat, the question lacks information. This is how I first thought it was meant. But there are several other possible ways as well. I'll await clarification before I do anything more.

Comment: @SmellyCat received_time is an entry that's recorded every second. I have attached sample of my data for one well with a unique well_id.

Comment: `WITH day_series AS (select generate_series('2024-01-22'::date, '2024-01-22'::date + '6 months'::interval, '1 day')  ... having received_time::date in day_series`?